# Android: Did Android 2.3.3 really full support 57 locales? /build/target/product/languages_full.mk only list 39 locales?

Tags: android, locale

Android SDK official website announce that it supports 57 locales.(http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.3.html#locs)

But in source code  /build/target/product/languages_full.mk, it only lists 39 locales are available. Why the two numbers of locales to support are not eqaul? And I checked the /res folder of every application in /packages/apps, most applications have 41~43 locales strings.

I have spent some time to search the answer on Internet. Could anyone help me to clarify what is different about these numbers for support locales?

Answer (score 0):

Look at German:

Spoken in:

German, Austria (de_AT)
German, Switzerland (de_CH)
German, Germany (de_DE)
German, Liechtenstein (de_LI)

But its still the same language